# Color box open more than 1 time in ajax generated content

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

So basically, i have a series of content which upon click, color box will show up.

```
echo '<div id=scrollimgforplaces>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<a class='ajax' href='image_color_box.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Utourpia'></a>";
echo '<a class="ajax" href="login_for_color_box.php" title="Login"></a>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

For the above static content, I call colorbox by using the below code:

```
$(".ajax").colorbox();
```

Next, I will be generating some of the dynamic content similar to this, to make colorbox works, i put the below codes in my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "data.php",
                    data:data,
                    success: function(res) {
        var $html = $(res);
            $html.find('a.ajaxdynamic').colorbox();
            $('#scrollimgforplaces').append($html);
                    }
                });
```

And my dynamic content is as follows:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<a class='ajaxdynamic' href='image_color_box.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Utourpia'></a>";
echo '<a class="ajaxdynamic" href="login_for_color_box.php" title="Login"></a>';
}
```

However, when I run the above codes, and i do some action, i.e. scroll down so that the dynamic content will show up. When i click the colorbox, it will show up two times, instead of once. Any idea what happened?

Demo page: http://utourpia.me/php/dreamtrip.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `$(".ajax").colorbox();` which applies colorbox to all elements with the *ajax* class.

You should try using an unique id something like `$("#element1").colorbox();`

**NOTE: I didn't tested my solution**